# Yaws with SSL gives the error "SSL accept failed: timeout"

Tags: ssl, timeout, yaws, certbot

I used certbot to generate a Let's encrypt certificate for my website, but Yaws gives me an `SSL accept failed: timeout` error when I try to connect to it (after it times out of course). Interestingly it works when I redirect `example.com` to the local ip address of the server in the hosts file on my machine and connect to `example.com:8080`, but not when I connect to `example.com` without editing the hosts file or when I connect from my phone over 4G. Here's my webserver's configuration file (it is the only configuration file in `conf.d`):

```
<server www.example.com>
    port = 8080
    listen = 0.0.0.0
    docroot = /usr/share/yaws
    <ssl>
        keyfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        certfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    </ssl>
</server>
```

I made sure that the keyfile and the certificate are both readable by the yaws user. Next to the keyfiles is a `README` that contains the following:

```
`privkey.pem`  : the private key for your certificate.
`fullchain.pem`: the certificate file used in most server software.
`chain.pem`    : used for OCSP stapling in Nginx >=1.3.7.
`cert.pem`     : will break many server configurations, and should not be used
                 without reading further documentation (see link below).
We recommend not moving these files. For more information, see the Certbot
User Guide at https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates.
```

So I'm relatively sure I've used the right file (the other ones gave me errors like `badmatch` and `{tls_alert,"decrypt error"}`). I also tried trivial things like writing `https://` before the URL, but it didn't fix the issue, also, everything works fine when the server is running without SSL. The version of Erlang running on my server is Erlang/OTP 19. Also, if it's unclear, the domain isn't actually `example.com`.

Also, `example.com` is redirected via cname to `examplecom.duckdns.org`, if that matters.

**UPDATE:**

My server was listening on port `8080`, that was forwarded from the external port `80`, for https connections, when the default https port is port `443`. My other mistake was connecting to `http://example.com` instead of `https://example.com`. Forwarding the external port `443` to the internal port `8443` and configuring yaws to listen on port `8443` fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure to understand, when you do something like `curl -v https://example.com:8080`, you get a timeout, that's it ? (here `https` protocol and port `8080` are mandatory of course)

SSL timeout during accept can be triggered when an unencrypted request is received on a SSL vhost.

Could you also provide the output of the following command:

```
echo -e "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect mysite.com:8080 -ign_eof
```

And finally, which version of Yaws are you running ? on which OS ?

Comment: Turns out I goofed up the port forwarding, ungoofing it fixed the problem. I edited the details into my original post.